# getenv(QUERY_STRING) Returning NULL

Tags: html, c, apache, cgi

I am currently trying to make a simple CGI Program that outputs someone's input in C.
Oddly, the environment variable "QUERY_STRING" is returning null.  Here is the code that I have, two simple files, one being a .html, and one being a .c.

simple.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void openHTML(char* path);
int main(){
        printf("Content-Type: text/html \n\n");
        openHTML("simple.html");
        char* data;
        data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
        printf("Data: %s", data);
        return 0;

}

void openHTML(char* path){
        //Opens File
        FILE* file = fopen(path, "r");
        //Reads through lines
        char line[256];

        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {

                printf("%s", line);
        }

        fclose(file);

}
```

simple.html

```
<html>
        <body>

                <form action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/simple.exe" method="post">
                        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
                        <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Current output:

```
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
        <body>

                <form action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/simple.exe" method="post">
                        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
                        <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
        </body>
</html>
Data: (null)
```

Comment: Just changed "post" to get and restarted apache, that seemed to fix it. Granted, I would however like it to be a post so that I can obtain the length so I'm going to keep looking at it. Let me know if you have any advice, thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface "If parameters are sent to the script via an HTTP GET request (a question mark appended to the URL, followed by param=value pairs; in the example, ?and=a&query=string), then those parameters are stored in the QUERY_STRING environment variable before the script is called. If parameters are sent to the script via an HTTP POST request, they are passed to the script's standard input."